# Как игнорировать создания документа при отсутствие даты?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Есть код, который должен создавать из данных в гугле таблице гугл документ. Если документ уже создан он не должен повторно создаваться, но проблема в том, что у меня таблица уже с номерами и код начинает создание лишнего документа и потом выдает ошибку и прекращает выполнение. Как сделать, чтобы код не создавал повторные документы и не создавал лишний документ, если дата отсутствует?

```
function createDocument() {
  var value = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('1s4rk03q4meZ2Ehr_MZyxFLfQr2XjJj9QWeOV97iMAjg', 'A2:R');
  var tamplate = '1Db4Zlm6Q0zCLQx62WLuqi63K4vPasWVXLfjJwsIdyl4';
  for (var i = 0; i <value.values.length; i ++){
  var number = value.values[i][0]; // Номер заявки
  var date = value.values[i][2]; //Дата
  var applicant = value.values[i][4]; // Заявитель
    var description = value.values[i][6]; //Описание
    var place = value.values[i][5]; //Место
    var executor = value.values[i][14]; //Исполнитель
    var complete = value.values[i][13]; //Выполненные работы
    console.log(date)
    var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(('Заявка № ' + number));
    if (files.hasNext() === true){
    }
    else{
  var documentId = DriveApp.getFileById(tamplate).makeCopy().getId();
  DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).setName('Заявка № ' + number);
    var body = DocumentApp.openById (documentId) .getBody ();
    body.replaceText('##Заявка №##', number);
    body.replaceText('##Дата##', date);
    body.replaceText('##Заявитель##', applicant);
    body.replaceText('##Описание##', description);
    body.replaceText('##Место##', place);
    body.replaceText('##Исполнитель##', executor);
    body.replaceText('##Выполненная работа##', complete);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно.  `if (files.hasNext() === true)` - этой проверкой вы же проверяете на создание дубля, разве нет? Такую же проверку на наличие даты сделайте

Comment: Уже решено https://qna.habr.com/q/895575 См. комментарии

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему.

```
if (files.hasNext() === true){
}
else if(date !== undefined){
```